# How do I get HDRP render enabled so that the shader graph will work

Tags: shaders, rendering, graph

I'm using Unity 2019.2.17 personal, and I imported the shader graph package and created a pbr shader graph.  I get a warning: the render pipeline is not compatible with the master node.  I assume it means I need to be using HDRP or LWDRP.  I can't figure out how to enable HDRP.  How do i do this?

Comment: Presumably you followed the [steps for setting up the HDRP detailed here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@6.7/manual/Upgrading-To-HDRP.html)? At what specific step of the process did you run into trouble?

Comment: thank you, that was all i needed.  one question though, how stable is HDRP.  will i run into much trouble, seeing as it's a preview package?

Comment: This was the first search result for "how to set up HDRP" so please take a bit more time to research your questions in future. You should post here when you have a question that is *not* easily answered by existing documentation and guides. We also will not be able to answer time-sensitive questions or judgement calls like "is technology X sufficiently stable to use as of this date?"